# Filtering DBpedia disambiguation page

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a SPARQL Query, and I want to eliminate all disambigution resources. How can I do this?  This is my query:

```sql
prefix rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 

select distinct ?Nom ?resource ?url where {
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   FILTER (langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following prefix and filter to your query:

```sql
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

filter not exists {
  ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?dis
}
```

This says to *exclude* resources and resources that redirect to a resources that disambiguate some articles.  That gives you a query like this:

```sql
prefix rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct ?Nom ?resource ?url where {
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   FILTER (langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
   filter not exists {
     ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?dis
   }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3FNom%20%3Fresource%20%3Furl%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fresource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FNom.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fresource%20foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf%20%3Furl.%0D%0A%20%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28%20lang%28%3FNom%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29%29.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3FNom%20%3Cbif%3Acontains%3E%20%22Apple%22.%0D%0A%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fresource%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%2Fdbo%3AwikiPageDisambiguates%20%3Fdis%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now, even though that removes all the disambiguation pages, you may still have results that include "disambiguation" in the title.  For instance, one of the results is:

The Little Apple (disambiguation)"@en
    http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Little_Apple_(disambiguation)

Even though that has "disambiguation" in the name, it's *not* a disambiguation page.  It doesn't have any values for **dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates**.   it does *redirect* to another page, though.  You may want to filter out things that redirect to something else, too.  You can modify the filter though:

filter not exists {
     ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects|dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?dis
   }

That says to filter out any resource that either redirects to something, or that disambiguates something.  This is actually a simpler filter, really.  This makes your query:

```sql
prefix rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct ?Nom ?resource ?url where {
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   FILTER (langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".

   filter not exists {
     ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects|dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?dis
   }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3FNom%20%3Fresource%20%3Furl%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fresource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FNom.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fresource%20foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf%20%3Furl.%0D%0A%20%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28%20lang%28%3FNom%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29%29.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3FNom%20%3Cbif%3Acontains%3E%20%22Apple%22.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fresource%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects%7Cdbo%3AwikiPageDisambiguates%20%3Fdis%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)